# Spring Config-server not finding plain text files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am running a spring cloud config server to provide application configs for several spring applications.  The configs are provided as `.yml` files in the directory specified as the base search path for the config server during startup:

`-Dspring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=/deploy-dir/config-dir`

The spring applications are able to get their configs as expected and I can also access the config manually (for app 'weather-service' and profile 'test') via GET at

`http://host:8888/weather-service/test/`

The returned body shows that the properties are being read from `"file:/deploy-dir/config-dir/weather-service-test.properties"`, and when I modify this file I can see the updates in the returned configs on the next call.  So this is working as expected.

However I also have some extra config information in the form of `.txt` and `.csv` files.  According to the [docs here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text), config server should be able to serve these files from the same directory (source: `config-dir/lookup_table.csv`), via an endpoint like this:

`http://host:8888/*/*/master/lookup_table.csv`

However **I am only getting `404` for any plain text (non-properties) file requests,** both from my application and via direct http call.
What might I be overlooking here?

Using springBoot version `1.5.2.RELEASE`, and spring-cloud `Dalston`. (*edit - same behavior when built with `Edgware.SR6`*)

From gradle build file used by config server:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.RC1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things, you're using a Release Candidate (RC1) that is not supported and Dalston is no longer supported. Can you update to Edgware.SR6 and try again?

Comment: Upgraded to Edgware.SR6, same behavior.  (had to add eureka healthcheck parameter to get local startup to work).

Comment: Is there any reason that csv file loading would only work when using a git repo backend?  Shouldn't it work with git OR file backend?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that config-server interprets the search path differently for properties and for files.

`spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=/deploy-dir/config-dir` will work fine for `.yml` and `.properties` files that live here, but other files must be handled differently if we want to serve them directly.

Fixed it by adding **"file:"**

`spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:/deploy-dir/config-dir`

Discovered via docs here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_file_system_backend

Comment: I was using search-locations instead of searchLocations on the property key for the folder. Thank you for the help. For unix based systems I did not need the file:/